# How to print literal string "$1" in bash script?

Tags: bash

I want to print string called "$1". But when I do this with echo it prints string which equals to "$1" variable. How can I print "$1" just like string?

for example:

```
set -- "output"  # this sets $1 to be "output"
echo $1          # ==> output
```

But I want this:

```
echo $1      # ==> $1
```

Comment: FYI, `$1=output` isn't actually valid syntax; I fixed up the example to actually *work* when run. :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to escape the `$` to have it shown:

```
$ echo "\$1"
```

or, as noted by JeremyP in comments, just use single quotes so that the value of `$1` does not get expanded:

```
$ echo '$1'
```

Comment: or `echo '$1'` (use single quotes)

Comment: your knowledge about shell is fantastic! you're awesome! ;)

Comment: Oh thanks @ZiyaddinSadigov, but you'll learn this and much more here in SO, it is what happened to me :D See you soon!

Answer (score 7):

You need to either:

- Enclose the variable in SINGLE quotes: `echo '$1'`
- Escape the `$` sign: `echo "\$1"`