# Quoting arguments with literal $s in bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to use a variable in a script to store a string that contains `$`s, and to pass that string unmodified as part of a command whose usage specifies that its argument should be in single quotes.

This works perfectly:

```
./mycommand -a 1 --arg='$a$a'
```

In the script, I'm trying to write it as follows:

```
args='$a$a'
./mycommand -a 1 --arg="'$args'"
```

The command doesn't accept the syntax it's passed as valid in this case. What could be wrong?

---

Additional edit: this script is to run hashcat, the password cracking program. I believe that it requires the single quotes for `--left-rule='$a$a'` and `--right-rule='$b$b'`, especially if there are any spaces in the rule.

Comment: You likely don't need the `''` around `$args` after `--arg` unless you intend them to be part of the argument.

Comment: The single quotes are necessary to run the command normally in the shell, so I have to use them in the script as well.

Comment: What if you try backslash escapes? Like that: `for iter in {1..10}; do ./command -a $iter --arg=\'\$a\$a\'; done`

Comment: I could try backslashes, but since the value of $args is a variable, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Well, does it really _need_ to be a variable? If so, depending on how this variable is set, it might be sufficient if you do the backslash escapes at the variable definition: `args=\'\$a\$a\'`

Comment: It does - I'm running a script that iterates through a thousand of these single quoted args. Any idea about the interactivity issue and having the commands run sequentially?

Comment: BTW, if you made this a bit more concrete, that might be helpful. `jq` is a specific command that can require this kind of calling convention -- is that the one you're actually using here? (If we knew that, we'd know what the *real* calling-convention requirements are, as opposed to how you're perceiving and describing them). BTW, `./command` is an exceptionally bad placeholder, since `command` is actually a shell built-in.

Comment: As for "the interactivity issue" -- that's a separate question, and should be asked separately. One question to a question, here.

Comment: that said, interactivity actually shouldn't be a problem in a `for` loop. It's usually something that's problematic if someone's using a `while read` or similar to iterate over file contents. When you're asking about interactivity issues, make sure that your question actually includes a reproducer for the problem -- something someone else can run to see the problem, and for which a modified/fixed version included in their answer can be verified to work by, well, running it.

Comment: Charles, you're absolutely right. My apologies. I'm writing a script that uses hashcat with --left-rule and --right-rule.

Comment: Okay. The hashcat docs are actually explicit on the wiki that the quotes are syntactic, rather than literal -- so meant for the shell to interpret.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, @CharlesDuffy! I assume this means that I can't have any spaces in my rules if that is the case?

Comment: Of course you can -- part of what syntactic quotes will do is force spaces between them to be seen as literals. `'foo bar'` is thus an *exact equivalent* of `foo\ bar` -- both are strings seven characters long, containing `foo`, a literal space, and `bar`. Which is *also* an exact match for `foo' 'bar` -- quoting contexts can be changed inline.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you! You're solving a lot of problems for me very quickly. Any idea on the interactivity issue?

Comment: You'd need to update your question with a tested reproducer for the interactivity bug for it to be answerable -- or, better, ask a second question that focuses on it specifically, since any such update would make @chepner's answer invalid (and updates that invalidate existing answers are frowned on here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy will do - thanks again.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines on building good code samples for questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print literal string "$1" in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445292/how-to-print-literal-string-1-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes inside the double quotes do not prevent expansion; they are literal characters. Compare:

```
$ a=5
$ echo "'$a$a'"
'55'
```

Since you just want to pass the literal string `$a$a` as an argument, it is sufficient to quote the parameter assignment; no additional single quotes are necessary:

```
args='$a$a'   # The literal string $a$a
./command -a $iter --arg="$args"  # $args expands to $a$a; no further expansion is attempted.
```

Comment: But, if the actual command, as run from prompt requires it as --arg='$a$a', using the single quotes in the shell, is there any way to include those? If var='\'$a$a\'', would that work?

Comment: The single quotes are only used by the shell to prevent `$a` from being expanded to the value of the parameter `a`. They are not *part* of the argument actually seen by `command`.

Comment: @Princey, ...or, to state what chepner told you a different way, if your command is documented as expecting `--arg='$a$a'`, that documentation is showing how to invoke the command from a shell, not what contents are actually expected to be present in a literal `argv` array entry. If you're **entirely certain** that this is wrong, and the quotes need to be literal, you could do `$'--arg=\'$a$a\''`, but that's... an extremely unlikely scenario.

Comment: `./command -a $iter --arg=\$a\$a` would work just as well the single quotes to escape the dollar signs.