# Regex with different character classes in Java

Tags: java, regex

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
        while ( m.find() )
            System.out.print(m.start()+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The above code when run with the commands

```
java MainTest "\b" "^23 *$76 bc"
java MainTest "\B" "^23 *$76 bc"
java MainTest "\S" "^23 *$76 bc"
java MainTest "\W" "^23 *$76 bc"
```

yields

```
1 3 5 6 7 9 
0 2 4 8 
0 1 2 4 5 7 8 
0 3 4 6
```

although I've almost made sure it would be

```
1 3 6 8 9 11
0 2 4 5 7 10
0 1 2 4 5 6 7 9 10
0 3 4 5 8
```

OK, so `\w` means `[0-9A-Za-z_]`, and `\b` should match any `\w` and `\W` boundary, and `\W` should match spaces and stuff not in `alnum+`underscore. Then, why am I getting these results? I came here to be freed of some of my serious misconceptions about regex in Java.

Comment: @Aaron: That's exactly what I'm saying. $, b, c are all non-space, too. Did you try running my code on your machine?

Comment: Ooh yeah nvm, I was looking at the wrong result -_-

Comment: Looks like your expected output to me when not using command line args: http://ideone.com/IbCykI

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your description makes it sound like the first output is the actual output (you say it yields that), but the second output is the actual output of the code. Is the first output your expectation, or what is going on here?

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, the first output is the actual output, the second one -- what I would expect.

Comment: When I run the code, I get the second output, using java 1.8.0_91 on Windows, i.e. when run with arguments `"\b" "^23 *$76 bc"` I get output `1 3 6 8 9 11`. What version of Java are you running?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: If you're on Linux, try printing your arguments, because your shell may corrupt your arguments, e.g. `$7` gets replaced with nothing, so your program actually sees arguments `\b` and `^23 *6 bc`.

Comment: I did print them. They are fine. And I run the programs with a script with lines "java MainTest "\b" "^23 *$76 bc", on each line.

Comment: Really? If you print `args[1]`, it prints the full value including `$7`? --- To remove the possibility of Linux shell interference, create a true [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): See this [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/VK8tXk). Voting to close as typographical error caused by Linux shell substitution. This is not an error in the Java regex engine. Unable to reproduce on Windows.

Comment: A dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445292/print-variable-1-as-string-in-bash-script?

Answer (score 1):

@Andreas is correct. The problem is in Linux shell: $7 gets replaced with nothing, and the command-line argument becomes "^23 *6 bc".

Comment: If you quoted using `'` instead of `"`, it should work. See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html#uh-1

Comment: @Andreas: feel free to answer this. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: The purpose of StackOverflow is to compile a compendium of answers to common (or not so common) questions. However, your question was about regex not working, and the solution is about using the correct quoting to prevent Linux shell substitution. It's unlikely that anyone will find this question/answer for similar shell substitution issues, so answering will not be generally useful. I'd suggest just deleting the question.

Comment: Ah, whatever -- I give a free hand to delete it, whoever has the rights to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I executed same program on Linux as well as Windows.
I found, Linux shell replaces **double** quoted arguments after symbol **$**
with their values (in your case, null as explained by Andreas ).
Here is sample code which will work on both OS

```
    System.out.println("0:"+args[0]);
    System.out.println("1:"+args[1]);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
    while ( m.find() )
        System.out.print(m.start()+" ");
    System.out.println();
```

and execute using single quote argument

```
java MainTest '\b' '^23 *$76 bc'
java MainTest '\B' '^23 *$76 bc'
java MainTest '\S' '^23 *$76 bc'
java MainTest '\W' '^23 *$76 bc'
```

Comment: Just a nitpick : `bash` has no `null` value ; the reference to the unbound variable `$7` will be resolved as the empty string when referenced (unless the shell's `nounset` flag has been set, in which case an error will be raised).