# How to echo literal output in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to "copy-paste" the following lines in a script into my `bashrc`:

```
# VIM,TMUX stuff
VIM="$(which vim)"
```

For example:

```
echo "# VIM,TMUX stuff" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'VIM="$(which vim)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

However, it seems to 'escape' some of the items. How would I do the equivalent of a literal 'copy-paste' as I'm trying to do above?

Comment: What's ending up in your `.bash_profile`? What you wrote looks good to me.

Comment: @JohnKugelman it expands the `$(which vim)` to a path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print literal string "$1" in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445292/how-to-print-literal-string-1-in-bash-script)

Comment: @David542 The single quotes would prevent that. Can you please copy-paste the code from your post into a new file and try again? This will prevent any mistakes in your original script from affecting the result.

Comment: @thatotherguy yes, that ended up working, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [heredoc in bash](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
cat <<-'EOF' > ~/.bash_profile
# VIM,TMUX stuff
VIM="$(which vim)"
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks -- could you please link to the docs where it says a bit more about that part?